Powershell formatting URL with variables prints System.objects[]
I have $startDa30te and $endDate that i want to add to URL address that is part of Powershell function. When I do that and write-host the URL address, it shows System.object[].
Both the $startDate and $endDate are strings, verified with $var.gettype(). And when I take that line out of the function and test in shell, it prints out as i except it to.
$startDate = "2024-08-01"
$endDate = "2024-09-30"
$teamUsers = "joe,tony,john"

function Getdata($startDate, $endDate, $teamUsers){
   $dataoff = @()
   $URL = "https://abc.myapi.com/v1/dataoff/?timeMin=$startDate&timeMax=$endDate"
   $URL
   foreach....

}

When I execute the funtion manually passing in the parameters, the URL would print out like https://abc.myapi.com/v1/dataoff/?timeMin=2024-08-01 2024-03-90 System.Object[]&timeMax
I've tried using -f and ` (back tick), + $statDate and $($startDate) but no luck. Would appreciate if someone can advise?

How are you calling Getdata?

Very likely calling GetData(foo, bar, baz) instead of GetData foo bar baz

Hi, Mathias. I would call it like GetData($startDate, $endDate, $teamUsers)

In short:
PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked like shell commands (arguments separated with spaces, no parentheses) - e.g. foo arg1 arg2 - not like C# methods - e.g. foo('arg1', 'arg2').
If you use , to separate arguments, you'll construct an array that a PowerShell-based command sees as a single argument.
With limitations and side effects, you can let PowerShell report an error when pseudo method syntax is attempted, via Set-StrictMode -Version 2 or above.
See the linked duplicates for details.

To spell it out: GetData $startDate $endDate $teamUsers
